# Otimização das conexões do MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, memória, conexão

Estou com uma dúvida pertinente com relação as conexões no meu banco de dados.

Me disseram que a cada nova conexão ao MySQL uma parte da memória RAM é reservada para essa conexão. Eu possuo diversas aplicações desenvolvidas em PHP e que conectam no mesmo banco de dados. Minha dúvida é: como funcionam as conexões com o banco no PHP e se existe uma forma de otimiza-las.

Pelo que eu sei, o cada vez que o script PHP executa, ele abre uma conexão com o banco e essa conexão dura, geralmente, até o fim da execução do script. Seguindo esse raciocínio, se o mesmo script for executado 10 vezes por clientes diferentes ou não ao mesmo tempo, ainda que por milésimos de segundo, teremos 10 conexões diferentes com o banco. Estou certo!? É isso mesmo que acontece na prática?

Se o raciocínio acima está correto e novas conexões com o banco são abertas sempre que o meu script PHP é executado, então uma parte da memória RAM é alocada dinamicamente pra cada execução do script, correto? Existe alguma forma de otimizar as conexões com o banco de dados de modo a reaproveitar as conexões abertas? Se possível, abrir uma única conexão por onde o script comunicará com o banco quantas vezes for necessário. Isso é possível?

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda. ;)

Comment: Bem vindo ao stack overflow, recomendo a leitura da [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para se ambientar com o site, ele funciona diferente de fórum. Por isso editei sua pergunta, aqui não tempos assinaturas :).

Comment: O ideal é que você mantenha um cache das requisições dentro do código php e evite acessar muitas vezes o banco de dados, somente acessando quando houver atualização ou inserção de dados. As consultas podem ser cacheadas, de maneira muito simples.

Comment: Ivan, nesse caso vamos partir do pressuposto de que eu não posso armazenar os dados em cache nem por alguns segundos.

Comment: tenho a mesma dúvida que você com relação as aplicações que acessam o mesmo banco. como sua pergunta é de 2015, acho que você ja aprendeu algo sobre. poderia me ajudar?

Comment: @Claytinho, o que eu fiz foi seguir a [sugestão do nosso amigo Sanção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90138/33535) e utilizar conexões persistentes. Assim, todas as requisições que partem do mesmo user@host utilizam uma única conexão.

Também defini um timeout de 30 segundos pra cada conexão inativa. Então, após esse período, uma conexão inativa é automaticamente fechada.

Comment: @VictorOtávio E você nunca teve problema com script travado impedindo novas conexões ou algo com transações? De qualquer forma agradeço a atenção. Vou tentar isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize conexões persistentes:

> Conexões persistentes são conexões que não fecham quando a execução do seu script termina. Quando uma conexão persistente é requisitada, o PHP verifica se já existe uma conexão persistente idêntica (que foi mantida aberta anteriormente) - e, se ela existir, ele a usa. Se ela não existir, ele cria a conexão. Uma conexão 'idêntica' é uma conexão que foi aberta para o mesmo host, com o mesmo nome de usuário e a mesma senha (onde for aplicável).

Fonte: [Conexões Persistentes com o Banco de Dados](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.persistent-connections.php).

---

Se você utiliza **PDO** basta informar a opção `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT` no construtor:

```
<?php
$conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
));
```

Se utiliza **mysqli** acrescente `p:` no endereço do servidor:

```
<?php
$conexao = new mysqli('p:localhost', $user, $pass, $database);
```

---

**Nota**: Não adicionei a forma para utilizando `mysql_connect()` pois a extensão foi descontinuada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4675/13561

Answer (score 2):

Olá, não sei bem se isso é válido no seu caso mas lhe trago uma dica: use o padrão de projeto singleton.
Basicamente ele busca usar a mesma instância de um objeto, e assim a mesma conexão com o banco de dados:

```
class Conexao {
//utilizando singleton
public static $instance;

public function __construct() {
    //construtor vazio singleton
}

public static function getInstance(){
    if(!isset(self::$instance)){
        self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=SERVIDOR;dbname=BANCO', 'USUARIO', 'SENHA', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>'SET NAMES utf8'));
        self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    return self::$instance;
}}
```

E substitua SERVIDOR, BANCO, USUARIO, SENHA por seus dados, para iniciar uma nova conexão use o código a seguir:

```
$conexao = Conexao::getInstance();
```

Assim você não "constrói" um novo objeto caso já tenha um construído.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, Natalia. Todas as minhas aplicações já trabalham assim. Minha dúvida é quando dois clientes diferentes executam o mesmo script, gerando, assim, duas conexões etc... :)

Comment: @Natalia Kelim Thiel

funciona como conexão persistente? Isso é bom para a mesma aplicação. No caso dum banco que serve vários servidores de aplicação, só otimize as aplicações individuais.

Comment: Bom, com dois clientes ao mesmo tempo não vai funcionar, mas já ajuda individualmente.